# php5-fpm doesn't create sockets for pools

Tags: linux, nginx, php-fpm, ubuntu-14.04

I'm going off of section 3.1 of http://www.howtoforge.com/php-fpm-nginx-security-in-shared-hosting-environments-debian-ubuntu .

I have created a directory in /var/run which www-data:www-data has rwxrwx permissions on.

My new pool config file consists of: http://pastebin.com/nmrJkMkz

However, upon restart of php5-fpm, /var/run/php5-fpm/domain.com.sock is not created as specified in the conffile. Nothing is in the error log of PHP5-FPM.

Any ideas as to why this may be occurring?

Comment: I would change the group of the `/var/run/php5-fpm` directory to `client`, which is the group php5-fpm uses. PHP5-FPM might have some restrictions about ownership of the directories for sockets.

Comment: Actually not a bad theory now that I think about it. Guess I had it in my head that FPM would create the sockets as www-data but change ownership to the user/group and spawn the process for the pool. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. Perhaps you forgot the **.conf** extension as i did.

So, try to rename your config file domain like this:

```
#File in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/

domain.com.conf
```

I hopê this help you !

Comment: Ahrr!!! Crap. I got exactly the same problem. Thanks for pointing to this!

Answer (score 0):

PHP-FPM will only create the file if it's defined within the /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf file

To solve the problem add this to the file

`listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock`

Make sure to also set these two

`listen.owner = nginx
 listen.group = nginx`

(Nginx or Apache default user)